# Parameters and NULL

Tags: r, postgresql

I'm having trouble passing NULL as an INSERT parameter query using RPostgres and RPostgreSQL:

In PostgreSQL:

```
create table foo (ival int, tval text, bval bytea);
```

In R:

This works:

```
res <- dbSendQuery(con, "INSERT INTO foo VALUES($1, $2, $3)", 
                   params=list(ival=1, 
                               tval= 'not quite null',
                               bval=charToRaw('asdf')
                               )
                    )
```

But this throws an error:

```
res <- dbSendQuery(con, "INSERT INTO foo VALUES($1, $2, $3)",
                   params=list(ival=NULL, 
                               tval= 'not quite null',
                               bval=charToRaw('asdf')
                               )
                   )
```

Using RPostgres, the error message is:

> Error: expecting a string

Under RPostgreSQL, the error is:

> ```
> Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
> RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  invalid input
> syntax for integer: "NULL"
> )
> ```

Substituting NA would be fine with me, but it isn't a work-around - a literal 'NA' gets written to the database.

Using e.g. integer(0) gives the same "expecting a string" message.

Comment: What gets written if you use an empty list? or use a numeric(0) or character(0)?

Comment: Zero-length items like numeric(0), integer(0), character(0) all trigger the same error. So does as.numeric(NA).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option here to workaround the problem of not knowing how to articulate a `NULL` value in R which the PostgresSQL pacakge will be able to successfully translate is to simply not specify the column whose value you want to be `NULL` in the database.

So in your example you could use this:

```
res <- dbSendQuery(con, "INSERT INTO foo (col2, col3) VALUES($1, $2)",
                   params=list(tval = 'not quite null',
                               bval = charToRaw('asdf')
                          )
                  )
```

when you want `col1` to have a `NULL` value.  This of course assumes that `col1` in your table is nullable, which may not be the case.

Comment: Thanks. I was coming around to this idea. I don't know in advance which (if any) of ival, tval, or bval will be NULL, and more than one can be NULL, so the dynamic query-building will be a bit trickier. So if there really isn't a "make the driver map R NULLs to db NULLS" option hiding under the hood, this is a good alternative.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `NULLIF` directly in your insert statement:

```
res <- dbSendQuery(con, "INSERT INTO foo VALUES(NULLIF($1, 'NULL')::integer, $2, $3)",
                   params=list(ival=NULL, 
                               tval= 'not quite null',
                               bval=charToRaw('asdf')
                               )
                   )
```

works with `NA` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks all for the help. Tim's answer is a good one, and I used it to catch the integer values. I went a different route for the rest of it, writing a function in PostgreSQL to handle most of this. It looks roughly like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_stuff(ii integer, tt text, bb bytea)
RETURNS integer
AS
$$
DECLARE
  bb_comp bytea;
  rows    integer;
BEGIN
  bb_comp = convert_to('NA', 'UTF8'); -- my database is in UTF8. 
  -- front-end catches ii is NA; RPostgres blows up 
  -- trying to convert 'NA' to integer.
  tt = nullif(tt, 'NA');
  bb = nullif(bb, bb_comp);
  INSERT INTO foo VALUES (ii, tt, bb);
  GET DIAGNOSTICS rows = ROW_COUNT;
  RETURN rows;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Now to have a look at the RPostgres source and see if there's an easy-enough way to make it handle NULL / NA a bit more easily. Hoping that it's missing because nobody thought of it, not because it's super-tricky.  :)

This will give the "wrong" answer if someone is trying to put literally 'NA' into the database and mean something other than NULL / NA (e.g. NA = "North America"); given our use case, that seems very unlikely. We'll see in six months time.