# Writing NULL into Postgresql database via Shiny app

Tags: r, postgresql, shiny

I have a ShinyApp that lets the user enter several input values which should be then stored in a postgresql database. The user is also able to modify entries which leads to the following problem:

If the user removes an existing textInput and tries to store an empty textInput in the database, the code does not convert the `NA` to give `NULL` over to PostgreSQL. It writes "NA" as a character into the database instead. This is my code snippet:

```
observeEvent(input$ActionButtonContinue, {
   df <- data.frame(
      column1 = ifelse(input$textInput != "", input$textInput, NA))

query <- "UPDATE table SET column1 = $1 WHERE id = 1"
parameters <- list(df$column1)

con <- getDBConnection() #a function that creates a connection to the database
dbExecute(con, query, parameters)
dbDisconnect(con)
})
```

If my textInput is empty, the cell is empty containing an `NA` and the textInput otherwise. `df$column1` also evaluates as `NA` with type `logical` if the textInput is empty. However, the database column1 contains `"NA"` instead of `[null]`.

Changing the query to `query <- UPDATE table SET column1 = NULL WHERE id = 1` works...

Thus my question, how do I pass over an `NA` such that Postgresql writes a `NULL` into the database? Since there are multiple inputs, it is not an option to hard code "NULL" into the query.

Comment: You'll need to replace `NA` by `"NULL"` or `"DEFAULT"` before building the query string (`ifelse` call). Regarding `"DEFAULT"` please see [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-update.html).

Comment: @ismirsehregal, this does not work. If I set ``df$column1 <- "NULL"`` or ``df$column1 <- "DEFAULT"`` before specifying the query, these strings are simply put into the database.

Comment: I left a working example below (yours isn't reproducible). I guess `dbExecute` quotes it's `parameters`.

Comment: Btw. NA should be mapped to NULL - see [this](https://github.com/r-dbi/RPostgres/issues/95#issuecomment-343213120). You might want to file an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39360936/parameters-and-null): `query <- UPDATE table SET column1 = NULLIF($1, 'NA')::text WHERE id = 1`  works.

Comment: See [NULLIF](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

`sprintf` can be used instead of `dbExecute`'s `parameters` argument to build the query string:

```
library(RPostgres)
library(DBI)
library(datasets)

dbConnection <- dbConnect(
  RPostgres::Postgres(),
  bigint="integer",
  dbname = "test",
  host = "localhost",
  port = 5432,
  user = "postgres",
  password = "postgres"
)


dbWriteTable(dbConnection, "iris", iris)
dbExecute(dbConnection, sprintf('UPDATE iris SET "Sepal.Width" = %s WHERE "Species" = \'setosa\';', "NULL"))
# dbReadTable(dbConnection, "iris")
```